# Худзенькия руки пырхали над клавишами(,) як матыльки над кветками

Tags: запятые, как

Как расставить запятые в предложении?
"Худзенькия руки пырхали над клавишами як матыльки над кветками".

Answer (score 4):

*Худзенькия руки пырхали над клавишами, **як** матыльки над кветками.*

Вариант (на русском языке): *Худенькие руки порхали над клавишами, **как** мотыльки **(порхают**) над цветами.*

Запятая **ставится**.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Это СПП с придаточным **сравнительным** предложением. Придаточное **неполное**, пропущено сказуемое. Як (как) — союз.
2. Здесь важно то, что это именно **неполное придаточное** (предикативная конструкция), а не сравнительный оборот. Предикативность легко восстанавливается, так как есть пара дополнений: *порхали **над клавишами** — порхали **над цветами**.*
3. Неполное **придаточное** всегда отделяется **запятой**, в отличие от **оборота**, который может обособляться или не обособляться (при обстоятельственном значении).

Comment: Я бы добавил, что эта фраза на белорусском диалекте (или, в политкорректной терминологии, на белорусском языке). Но, как я понимаю, там соблюдаются те же правила в отношении придаточных предложений.

Comment: Да, согласна с вами, поэтому не стала обсуждать орфографию, а привела русский аналог.

Answer (score 1):

Оставляя на совести автора орфографию и делая догадку о сути вопроса исключительно по тегу, отвечу: "Худзенькия руки пырхали над клавишами, як матыльки над кветками". Здесь те же правила, что и для употребления "как": запятая ставится, поскольку фраза не входит в сказуемое.

Comment: Вечер добрый! Пишете, что *запятая ставится*. А у вас её нет. Вот похожее предложение: *Она играла их с закрытыми глазами, руки ее **летали над клавишами, как золотые стрекозы в лучах света**, шея была склонена, губы приоткрыты — она дышала музыкой* (С. Греджо. Голыми руками).

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Не очень похожее. Здесь сравнительный оборот, а там неполное сравнительное придаточное. И можно ли здесь вообще говорить о сказуемом.  Порхали как мотыльки – это может быть СИС?