# Нужно ли обособлять сравнительный оборот?

Tags: запятые, грамматика, сравнительный-оборот

*Синее небо, солнце в зените, а главное — летучие рыбы. Замечательно красивые рыбки!*

(1) *Порхают(?) **как стрекозы**, дразнят душу старого моряка.*

(2) *Порхают(,) **как стрекозы**, взглядом не уследишь!*

Нужно ли **обособлять** оборот в этих вариантах? Решения одинаковые или **разные**? Если оборот не обособляется, то какой это **член предложения**? Может ли оборот входить **в сказуемое?**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Вопрос продолжает тему [другого вопроса на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476994/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Нужно было сопоставить придаточное сравнительное **предложение** и сравнительный **оборот** на основе глагола ***"порхать".***

Я нашла подходящий текст, а потом максимально упростила оборот, чтобы **не обособлять** его. Но в полученном предложении он вроде бы обособлялся. Тогда я добавила вариант, где оборот вроде бы не обособляется.

2. Но почему **"вроде бы"**, разве нет точного ответа? В чем сомнения?

Так это сравнительный оборот, **трехчастная структура**! Там всегда, с точки зрения лингвистики, **два решения:** обособленное сравнение/определение и необособленное обстоятельство. А **выбор** обычный: семантика, грамматика, интонация.

3. **Интонация** не особо помогает (оба варианта возможны). Остается анализ **семантики**, грамматики, структуры.
4. Но ведь **правила** еще есть!  Да, есть, а вот однозначность в них тоже не просматривается. Это тоже анализ и выбор подходящего варианта.  Но можно попробовать решить по правилам.
5. Есть еще **интуитивный выбор** — **вроде бы!** Он как раз обозначен в первых комментариях.

Comment: Я бы обособил. Думаю, нужно. Нет-нет, еще раз: ДУМАЮ, нужно. Да, так лучше.

Comment: Вы не различаете варианты по смыслу? Ведь решение может быть разным.

Comment: в первом однородные

Comment: А почему сомнения возникли?

Comment: Серж, теперь здесь столько сомнений, что  я не знаю, о чем вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Почему сомнения в запятых?

Comment: Так это сравнительный оборот!  Трехчастная структура и все такое. Там всегда, с точки зрения лингвистики, два решения. А выбор обычный: семантика, грамматика, интонация.  Приведите, пожалуйста, ваше решение, желательно в ответе.